# Как корректно заполнить словарь (2 ключа) значениями из списка (2 значения)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы, словари

Есть базовый словарь с двумя ключами и список содержащий два других словаря:

```
base_dict = {"key1": "", "key2": ""}

new_list = [{"key1_1": "", "key2_1": ""}, {"key1_2": "", "key2_2": ""}]
```

Не могу корректно заполнить базовый словарь из двух ключей соответствующими значениями из списка также содержащего два словаря:

```
for currency in list_currency:
     for i in range(len(new_list)):
         base_dict[currency] = new_list[i]
```

По факту получается заполнить базовый словарь только первым значением из списка, т.е оба ключа `base_dict` содержат значения только первого элемента/значения списка `new_list`, а необходимо чтобы первый ключ `base_dict` содержал значение первого элемента списка, второй ключ `base_dict` содержал значение второго элемента списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу сказать точно почему не работает Ваш код. Если создавалась новая пара ключ-значение, то скорее всего в list_currency хранились не существующие в base_dict
ключи. Вариант кода ниже должен работать.

```
base_dict = {"key1": "", "key2": ""}

new_list = [{"key1_1": "", "key2_1": ""}, {"key1_2": "", "key2_2": ""}]
for currency in base_dict.keys():
    for i in new_list:
        base_dict[currency] = i
```